# size_t on XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-c++, gcc, stl

It seems on XCode I need to use std::size_t instead of just size_t on Visual C++. But this is a pain as I don't really want to have to `#include <cstddef>` and change every `size_t` to `std::size_t` in my code... in my Windows code `size_t` just works without including any additional files.

Is there a way to make my existing code work in XCode, (maybe through the .pch file?) or are GCC/MSVC++ fundamentally different in this regard and my code needs to use `std::size_t` in order to be cross-platform?

Comment: Is one line of `sed` really that much work?

Comment: Why not use `#include <stddef.h>` instead? Then you can use `size_t`.

Comment: God forbid you have to make your code _correct_...

Comment: The whole difference between cstddef and stddef.h is that the former puts the contents into namespace std, while the latter puts them into the top-level namespace. So if you want to use cstddef, use std::size_t (possibly with a using); if you don't want size_t in std, use stddef.h. Either one is perfectly reasonable and valid, but trying to use cstddef and not namespace std is not reasonable (even if it happens to work with one compiler/library/platform).

Comment: @pmr it is if you've never heard of `sed`. Could you write an answer explaining what this one line would be :)

Comment: @ildjarn correct is not an absolute term :)

Comment: @John : It is in this case -- including `cstddef` has behavior mandated by an ISO standard.

Comment: @pmr: A tutorial for sed can be found at http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html. You'll want to use it in combination with find -exec, for which a tutorial can be found at http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/Find/find_mini_tutorial.shtml. The manpages are also very useful. I'll put one-liners as comments on each of the solutions, if you just want to do it without understanding what you're doing, but I'd recommend learning find and sed, as they're incredibly useful tools that every programmer should know. Alternatively, you can use the MSVC GUI find tools to do the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the C++03 standard, 17.4.1.2.4:

> Except as noted in clauses 18 through 27, the contents of each header cname shall be the same as that of the corresponding header name.h, as specified in ISO/IEC 9899:1990 Programming Languages C (Clause 7), or ISO/IEC:1990 Programming Languages—C AMENDMENT 1: C Integrity, (Clause 7), as appropriate, as if by inclusion. In the C++ Standard Library, however, the declarations and definitions (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope (3.3.5) of the namespace std.

In other words, by choosing to use `<cstddef>` instead of `<stddef.h>`, you're specifically asking for the type size_t to be within the namespace std.

So, here are the choices:

1. Use `<stddef.h>` instead, so `size_t` is in the top-level namespace, as suggested by Jesse Good.
2. Use `<cstddef>` and use `std::size_t`.
3. Use `<cstddef>` and use a using declaration to pull `size_t` into the top-level namespace, as suggested by cnicutar.

Of course you could rely on the fact that one particular version of one compiler/library/platform lets you get away with it, or write different code for each platform, or wrap the whole thing up with autoconf, or write a code generator or sed-based preprocessor, or whatever… but why?

Comment: I realised I can combine your answer, without having to change my  code files to all do the `#include`, by adding the `#include <stddef.h>` to the XCode preprocessed header. Which AFAIK emulates VC++ injecting it into the global namespace.

Comment: Sure. You could also pass it as a -include parameter to the compiler (which is very easy to do in either an Xcode project or a makefile). The only problem is that it makes your code a little misleading to a reader/maintainer. In this case, it's trivial enough that it probably doesn't matter—but if it were me, I'd sed all the source files instead.

Comment: Thank you. The three choices were really helpful. I read multiple sites and still couldn't get it. It's clear now! :)

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps saying this somewhere near the top ?

```
using std::size_t;
```

Comment: rather `using namespace std;`, not?

Comment: @H2CO3 I find that a bit over reaching. Then again, I don't know much C++.

Comment: using namespace std; pollutes the whole scope with std nonsense, avoid that whenever possible

Comment: Just use `#include <stddef.h>`.

Comment: Good answer, but it would be better if it explained _why_ he needs to do this. (See my comment to the main question above.) @Jesse Good: You should write that as a second answer, because they're both equally valid, and I'd upvote both of them.

Comment: @abarnert I didn't know that. You can edit my answer, what you wrote is highly informative :-)

Comment: @John: One way or another, you have to edit hundreds of code files. You could replace every "size_t" with "std::size_t", replace every "<cstddef>" with <stddef.h>, or replace every "<cstddef>" with "<cstddef>\nusing std::size_t;", any of which are pretty trivial with sed or MSVC's Find and Replace in Files or whatever you prefer.

Comment: find . -name '*c' -exec sed -e 's/<cstddef>/<cstddef>\ACTUAL-NEWLINE-HERE-WHICH-THE-COMMENT-SYSTEM-WILL-EAT
using std::size_t;/g' -i.bak '{}' \;

Answer (score 4):

Use `#include <stddef.h>`.

So, what's the difference between `#include <stddef.h>` and `#include <cstddef>`?

`<cstddef>` is a C++ header and is guaranteed to define all symbols in the `std` namespace and also *may* define things in the global namespace.

`<stddef.h>`is a C header and is guaranteed to define all symbols in the global namespace and *may* also define things in the `std` namespace.

So, as you said on Visual Studio, `size_t` can be used because it injects `size_t` into the global namespace for you (possibly by already including "stddef.h"). If you want that to work on any compiler include `stddef.h`.

(However, as a pure C++ fan, I personally prefer `std::size_t`).

Comment: +1 for the parenthetical comment. Especially since the standard is a bit unclear as to whether the C libraries are actually available in C++ (although as far as I know, every implementation does make them available).

Comment: Visual C++ knows about `size_t` because it is used by `sizeof` and `new`. This "leaks" to user programs even before including any headers. A known bug.

Comment: @BoPersson: Useful bit of info.

Comment: find . -name '*c' -exec sed -e 's/<cstddef>/<stddef.h>/g' -i.bak '{}' \;