# # include <cstddef> file not found in xcode

Tags: c++, iphone, ios

Hello i am using this [library](https://github.com/xil3f/podofo_iOS_sample) for implementation of annotation but facing one issue in bellow image
[image]
i checked user header path and library search path and
  also try this link:

[size_t on XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823878/size-t-on-xcode)

[Xcode cannot find cstddef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304545/xcode-cannot-find-cstddef)

Please Help Me

Comment: That's a C++ header and yet you haven't tagged your question with objective-c++, which rings some alarm bells...

Comment: @trojanfoe I see this question being tagged with `xcode++` in the very near future...

Comment: @trojanfoe sorry for my mistake but solve my issue

Comment: Huh?  Do you mean "yes, I have now started using Objective-C++ and that's solved my issue, thanks" or do you mean "Yeah, whatever, just solve my problem already"?

Comment: @trojanfoe I think the latter ;)

Comment: Yeah, me too.  I wonder if I'll comply?

Comment: @trojanfoe i tire  to change Compiler Sources as is  Objective-C++ but app crashs when pdf file read

Comment: @trojanfoe Well, it's up to you, you good samaritan :)

Comment: Well, OK.  That URL you reference is a sample project where all files are `.m` apart from one which is `.mm`.  Do you think this is important?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the reason is that the implementation file, that includes the header from that library, needs to be Objective-C++.

This is easily fixed by renaming it from `.m` to `.mm`.

It will also be necessary to avoid exposing the library to the rest of your project if you are unwilling to make the whole app Objective-C++ and I believe the sample project you reference does this as all implementation files are Objective-C apart from one which is Objective-C++.

Doing that is non-trivial.

Comment: after rename  getting erro terminate called throwing an exception (lldb)

Comment: @kirtimali I knew it was a mistake to post an answer.

Comment: posted error is solved  thank you ,after excess bad error occur

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks for this answer. I have spent way to much time figuring out what the f... with my framework :D

Comment: @LarsNielsen I should have mentioned in my answer that the `#if defined` line in the OP's question is wrong.  It's trying to determine whether it's being compiled into C++ code and so would be better off either using `__cplusplus` in the `#if` or simply always doing `#include <stddef.h>`.